# Is there a way to change the display length of an Envelope Custom Field?

Tags: docusignapi

I have an Envelope Custom Field of type Text and would like to make the display longer as entries will be longer than the current display. Is there a configuration somewhere that I can change to make the display longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the Custom Fields section at the bottom of the sending page, then I believe the answer is no. There is no configuration option which will make these text boxes display larger in the DocuSign web console.